# What would you call one parent who acts as both the mother and father to a child?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there was a word for when a parent has to act as a mother and father to a child either because the parent is single and the other parent is absent from the child's life.
Thank you!

Comment: He or she is a single-parent.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. In your question, you use the construct *either ... and*. It's normally rendered *either ... or* - did you intend that "single" and "absent" were the alternatives, or is there a missing alternative in your question?

Comment: Define "act as mother" and "act as father", including how you think they differ.

Comment: This is a potentially touchy subject.  Some families have two parents of the same gender.  They might take issue with the implicit assumption that there *are* two distinct parental roles to be played.

Answer (score 0):

Single-parent will do in this case.

> **Single parent** *noun*
>   A person bringing up a child or children without a partner.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/single_parent)

Comment: Hello and welcome. You seem to be new here, based on your rep count. I wasn't the down-voter, but thought I'd mention that Stack Exchange is about building a repository of expert answers to questions within the topics of interest to its various communities. As such, answers are usually expected to be supported by logical argument, references and/or usage examples. They don't need to be complicated; the idea is for answers to be independently verifiable. I've added a dictionary entry for you.

Comment: In the case of this question, consider also the second part to the OP's description. When the other parent is absent from the child's life but the parent isn't single (I'm reading the 'and' in the question as a typo for an 'or' because of the earlier 'either'), *single parent* doesn't seem to fit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  One is *single parent*, as Nach contributed, although I would not use a hyphen -- in the U.S. at least.

The other way is like this:

> My wife died young and left me with three motherless girls.  It was hard.  I had to be *both mother and father* to them.

When you choose this approach, it is most common to use it as in my example, with "had to be".

Note that the other, non-participating parent need not have died for this phrase to be used.